# Python select ROI OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yEqA.jpg)

Hello,

I created an application in python that select the Region of Interest(ROI) of an image, record and label it. But I has a limit of one ROI per image, anyone know how to have multiple selection of ROI per image? Also on attached image, as you can see I have multiple window, I want it to be in one window with different options, what packages are use on this kind of application.

here's my code in python using opencv2. Thank you in advance for the help

```
  for image in filelist:
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    fromCenter = False
    r = cv2.selectROI(img, fromCenter)

    lbl = simpledialog.askstring("Image Label", "Please Enter Label")

    result = eTree.SubElement(results, "Image")

    path = eTree.SubElement(result, 'Path')
    roi = eTree.SubElement(result, 'ROI')
    label = eTree.SubElement(result, 'Label')

    path.text = str(image)
    roi.text = str(r)
    label.text = str(lbl)

    tree = eTree.ElementTree(results)
    i = i + 1
    if i == count:
        format = [('XML Files', '*.xml'), ('All Files', '*.*')]
        save = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetype=format, defaultextension='*.xml')
        tree.write(save, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', method="xml")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well at least for the first part of the question, have you considered to try the `cv2.createROIs()` instead of `cv2.createROI()` ? When the image window is opened you then select your first ROI and press enter, then the second and press enter etc. And when you are finished then press the escape key. It returns x,y,w,h of each ROI. Note that you will have to change your code accordingly but it will allow you to select multiple ROI.

Input image:

[image]

Example:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('rois.png')

fromCenter = False
ROIs = cv2.selectROIs('Select ROIs', img, fromCenter)

ROI_1 = img[ROIs[0][1]:ROIs[0][1]+ROIs[0][3], ROIs[0][0]:ROIs[0][0]+ROIs[0][2]]
ROI_2 = img[ROIs[1][1]:ROIs[1][1]+ROIs[1][3], ROIs[1][0]:ROIs[1][0]+ROIs[1][2]]
ROI_3 = img[ROIs[2][1]:ROIs[2][1]+ROIs[2][3], ROIs[2][0]:ROIs[2][0]+ROIs[2][2]]

cv2.imshow('1', ROI_1)
cv2.imshow('2', ROI_2)
cv2.imshow('3', ROI_3)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thankyou it works. How about the idea of making it in one window with image panel of the selected images? Do you have idea atleast what packages I need to use? Thanks

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by one window with image panel...like a GUI? If that is the case you should try tkinter or pyqt module

Comment: It return some error: IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1.

Comment: @shahar_m I reproduced IndexError if no ROI is selected when exiting image. Read the answer on how to use this code please. I have just tested it and it still works.

Answer (score 1):

For custom ROI you can use [EasyROI](https://github.com/saharshleo/easyROI). It supports rectangle, line, circle and polygon.

For using it:

```
pip install EasyROI

from EasyROI import EasyROI  
roi_helper = EasyROI()  
roi = roi_helper.draw_rectangle(frame, quantity=2)
```